# photo gallery based on mysql data using the paging system twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination, photo-gallery

I've successfully made ​​a photo gallery based on mysql database, but I want to make it into multiple pages ( one page show only several picture, not one page show all my picture data base), I'm confused how to use pagination  the twitter bootstrap to my code, whether you can give an example to me, or even a link to the tutorial.....( sorry i'm a newbie )

This is my example code:

`

```
<div class="sub-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <h4 class="bot-0">pict gallery</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php  while($mydata=mysql_fetch_object($pict_colection)) {?>
            <div class="thumbnails_4">
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="thumbnail thumbnail_4">
                        <figure>
                            <a href="
                                <?php echo $mydata->location; ?>" class="magnifier">
                                <img src="
                                    <?php echo $mydata->location; ?>" class="img-radius" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

`

Comment: try to explain more.. show some code which u have tried..

Comment: thank for your reply, now you can see my code and i hope you understand my code, sorry i'm a newbie

Comment: Since I am not a php expert.. but I guess there is certain issue with your `mysql_fetch_object` method. if possible try to unhide some more code behind the scene, so that some php guy can have a look on this :)